# Is it possible to scale drawableleft & drawableright in textview?

Tags: android, textview

I have `TextView` with `drawableLeft` & `drawableRight` in List item. 
The problem is, whenever the height of `TextView` is larger, `drawableLeft` & `drawableLeft` didn't automatically scale based on the height of the `TextView`.

Is it possible to scale the height of `drawableLeft` & `drawableRight` in `TextView` ?
(I was using 9 patch image)

[image: textview drawableleft & drawableright's height problem]

Comment: use this link: [edit text compound drawables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471026/edittext-with-non-selectable-grayed-out-prefix)

Comment: you can modify the following for the textview. Also the parameters for setCompound drawable has option for drawable right, drawable left.void android.widget.                TextView.setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)

Comment: thanks :)
but it doesn't work, still the image can't stretch. I try to set the drawable bound using textview height (textview.getHeight()), but it is return the text view design height not current height.

Comment: ok, I use background instead; and now it is work :)

Answer (score 41):

This might help you out. 
There are two properties **scaleX** and **scaleY**

The code below will scale down the image and the text with 30%. 
Therefore you have to increase the font size with that many "sp", so that when it get re-sized (scaled) it would fit the "sp" you prefer.

Example. If I set the font to 18, then 30% out of 18 is 5.4sp, so roughly, this is the value I am targeting at, because when it gets scaled, it would become 13sp

```
<TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:scaleX="0.7"
        android:scaleY="0.7"
```

The last thing to do is set the CompundDrawable.

```
tview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx), null, null, null);
```

Comment: I'm sure is not the most elegant, but I've tried many things and it was getting too complex for such an easy thing to ask. Thanks!

Comment: not sure why people are saying this is a good solution... this is a very unscalable and inelegant solution since you need to muck around with sp values to find what works. please see my answer, ImageViews should be used as they were intended to scale. TextView only has a drawable property for ease of use it does not cover every single use case you'd ever want to do with an image like scaling it. Use the SDK as it's intended.

Comment: What if you only want to scale the image?

Answer (score 31):

Wrap your resource in a drawable that defines your desired size similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/icon"
      android:width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:height="@dimen/icon_size" />

</layer-list>
```

After that, use this drawable in your textview tag

Comment: Available only api 23 and up

Comment: This is the cleanest answer, allowing you to keep all layout code in the XML's without introducing multiple views (ImageView + TextView). Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Hope this help

```
Textview tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_dummy)
int imageResource =  R.mipmap.ic_image;
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, imageResource);
int pixelDrawableSize = (int)Math.round(tv.getLineHeight() * 0.7); // Or the percentage you like (0.8, 0.9, etc.)
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, pixelDrawableSize, pixelDrawableSize); // setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom), in this case, drawable is a square image
tv.setCompoundDrawables(
 null, //left
 null, //top
 drawable, //right
 null //bottom
);
```

Answer (score 11):

The only acceptable answer here should be to use an ImageView with the scaleTypes as per usual. Hacky work arounds to scale an image on a TextView that isn't supported by Android seems.. unnecessary. Use the SDK as it was intended.

Comment: Wrapping a Textview and ImageView together in a LinearLayout spawns a notice about using CompoundDrawables. I guess the question is whether to use the API as "intended" or as "recommended" by the people who wrote it.

Comment: I don't think imageview is not a good solution to this problem. It's clearly something that needs fixing at the UI level.

Comment: @AbandonedCart I guess the notice may give a hint to developers that there's also `CompoundDrawables`, but in the end, I think depends on the use case, the `TextView`+`ImageView` combination might be more suitable (or even, the only solution).

Comment: @AndrewT. It is not the only solution, since even your reply pointed out that two exist. I think you may have missed the point of my comment. If this is "as it was intended" then there would be no reason for the SDK to be suggesting something else.

Answer (score 10):

I solved an equivalent usecase by introducing a `ScaleDrawable` and overriding its `.getIntrisicHeight()` so that it is at least the `TextView` height. The `TextView.addOnLayoutChangeListener` part, required to rebind the `Drawable` on a `TextView` size change works with API11+

```
Drawable underlyingDrawable = 
        new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), result);

// Wrap to scale up to the TextView height
final ScaleDrawable scaledLeft = 
        new ScaleDrawable(underlyingDrawable, Gravity.CENTER, 1F, 1F) {
    // Give this drawable a height being at
    // least the TextView height. It will be
    // used by
    // TextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return Math.max(super.getIntrinsicHeight(), 
                        competitorView.getHeight());
    };
};

// Set explicitly level else the default value
// (0) will prevent .draw to effectively draw
// the underlying Drawable
scaledLeft.setLevel(10000);

// Set the drawable as a component of the
// TextView
competitorView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
        scaledLeft, null, null, null);

// If the text is changed, we need to
// re-register the Drawable to recompute the
// bounds given the new TextView height
competitorView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, 
            int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        competitorView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(scaledLeft, null, null, null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I did not found way. But that you show looks like a list of items. Each item would be a LinearLayout horizontal with imagesView from left to right and text in center. The image dimension do a  android:scaleType="fitXY" for ajust the size height to the textview height.
If you want no deform de image use scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE". http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/HeaderList" 
     android:layout_gravity="top"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  


     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/backImg"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:background="@color/blancotransless"
         android:src="@drawable/header"
         android:scaleType="fitXY" >
     </ImageView>

         <TextView 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:id="@+id/NameText"
             android:text="The time of prayer" 
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
             android:textSize="30sp" 
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
             android:paddingLeft="4dp"
             android:paddingTop="4dp" 
             />
    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/backImg"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:background="@color/blancotransless"
         android:src="@drawable/header"
         android:scaleType="fitXY" >
     </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've used this solution successfully because I couldn't scale left/right drawables as the question suggests

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to create a custom size for the drawable inside the TextView is by using the BindingAdapter. Using this, you will be able to set you image size in your xml.

For example, TextViewBindingAdapter.java

```
public class TextViewBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter({"android:imageSize"})
    public static void bindIconSize(TextView textView, int size) {
        Drawable[] drawables = textView.getCompoundDrawables();
        if(drawables[0] != null) {
            drawables[0].setBounds(0, 0, size, size); // setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom), in this case, drawable is a square image
            textView.setCompoundDrawables(
                    drawables[0], //left
                    null, //top
                    null, //right
                    null //bottom
            );
        }
        if(drawables[1] != null) {
            drawables[1].setBounds(0, 0, size, size); // setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom), in this case, drawable is a square image
            textView.setCompoundDrawables(
                    null, //left
                    drawables[1], //top
                    null, //right
                    null //bottom
            );
        }
        if(drawables[2] != null) {
            drawables[2].setBounds(0, 0, size, size); // setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom), in this case, drawable is a square image
            textView.setCompoundDrawables(
                    null, //left
                    null, //top
                    drawables[2], //right
                    null //bottom
            );
        }
        if(drawables[3] != null) {
            drawables[3].setBounds(0, 0, size, size); // setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom), in this case, drawable is a square image
            textView.setCompoundDrawables(
                    null, //left
                    null, //top
                    null, //right
                    drawables[3] //bottom
            );
        }


    }
}
```

Now, in your .xml you can set the android:imageSize.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/alpha_s_circle"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:imageSize="@{300}"/>
```

And don't forget to set in your gradle.build this code below:

```
android {
    ....
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make 9-path background repeating this pattern.

And also it seems it will be better look in case the pattern will be applied to the list, not to  individual item.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution would be to override `TextView`. Here's an example:

https://gist.github.com/hrules6872/578b52fe90c30c7445a2

I changed a bit:

```
private void resizeCompoundDrawables() {
    Drawable[] drawables = getCompoundDrawables();
    if (compoundDrawableWidth > 0 || compoundDrawableHeight > 0) {
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            if (drawable == null) continue;

            Rect realBounds = drawable.getBounds();

            float drawableWidth = realBounds.width();
            if(this.compoundDrawableWidth>0)
                drawableWidth = this.compoundDrawableWidth;
            float drawableHeight = realBounds.height();
            if(this.compoundDrawableHeight>0)
                drawableHeight = this.compoundDrawableHeight;

            realBounds.right = realBounds.left + Math.round(drawableWidth);
            realBounds.bottom = realBounds.top + Math.round(drawableHeight);

            drawable.setBounds(realBounds);
        }
    }
    super.setCompoundDrawables(drawables[0], drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);
}
```

This way you can set the size of the drawable but if you care about width/height ratio make it the way suits you.

Now if you want it to automatically match height of the textview you may also override the `TextView`'s method `onSizeChanged`:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    compoundDrawableHeight = h;
    resizeCompoundDrawables();
}
```

You my also want to declare sizes for each side, for example leftCompoundDrawableWidth, rightCompoundDrawableWidth and so on.

Note that it does not work with a [Shape](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable) as drawable. Sounds like `TextView` only accepts it if it has the size attributes, that way one can implement it by updating the size of the shapedrawable using setSize or setIntrinsicWidth or ... Not tested.

Comment: this might work well, you can also add in code to make sure the drawable is tinted the same as the text, if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's worth look at **ImageSpan**. It's a span that replaces the text it's attached to with a Drawable that can be aligned with the bottom or with the baseline of the surrounding. I think it will automatically scale it as well based on the height of the textview.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan

Answer (score 0):

I Tried all the solutions but none of them worked for me, then I tried this one

in `TextView`

```
           <TextView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/product_view_count"
            android:text="@string/view_product_count"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_eye"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

in your Activity or fragment or Adapter. I am using my adapter like this

```
viewcount=itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_view_count);

holder.viewcount.setPivotX(0);
holder.viewcount.setPivotY(0);
holder.viewcount.setScaleX(.7f);
holder.viewcount.setScaleY(.7f);
```

by using `ScaleX, ScaleY` in `TextView` text position will change. to keep the position in `left/start` using `setPivotX,setPivotY`

Thank's to **[Bö macht Blau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015207/b%C3%B6-macht-blau)** for the nice solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160705/how-to-scale-a-view-without-it-moving-x-y-position)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to create a new drawable and adjust the drawable objects size

```
 <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    **android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"**
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="@android:color/white">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/black"
      android:pathData="M19,3H4.99C3.89,3 3,3.9 3,5l0.01,14c0,1.1 0.89,2 1.99,2h10l6,-6V5C21,3.9 20.1,3 19,3zM7,8h10v2H7V8zM12,14H7v-2h5V14zM14,19.5V14h5.5L14,19.5z"/>
</vector>
```