# android: fit height of DrawableLeft in a textView

Tags: android, drawable

I am trying to display a blue line next to a block of text, pretty much like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue_line" />
```

blue_line is a jpg file. a blue rectangle. it displays in its original size regardless of the text in the textview. how can i adjust its height dynamically according to the height of the text? like make it shorter when theres little amount of text and longer when there's more text....

Comment: Use a QuoteSpan or one of LeadingMarginSpan

Comment: i tried quotespan it seems awesome, but is there any way to increase the width of the line? and how to use leadingmarginspan?

Comment: I think this could be an accurate work-around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934868/6094503

Answer (score 32):

You can try doing it in code by setting bounds for the image

```
textView1.getViewTreeObserver()
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Drawable img = ActivityName.this.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.blue_line);
            img.setBounds(0, 0, img.getIntrinsicWidth() * textView1.getMeasuredHeight() / img.getIntrinsicHeight(), textView1.getMeasuredHeight());
            textView1.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
            textView1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: In my case parent container of this view is View.GONE on create. That causes getMeasuredHeight() == 0 and image also gets zero size. I have solved this by using textView1.getLineHeight() instead of  textView1. getMeasuredHeight() in both cases.

Comment: why does it have to be done in "onGlobalLayout"? and not just in "onCreate" when setting the image for the first time as compundDrawable?

Comment: @EladBenda This needs to be done in OnGlobalLayoutListener because this is called when a view is drawn, you will get correct height and width of the view only when it is drawn. In onCreate method the view has not drawn yet so you will get height and width as 0.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do this is to wrap your drawable in an xml drawable file and set it as a drawable in your text view as follows:

Drawable XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/total_calories"/>
```

TextView in XML:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title_total_cal"
    style="@style/title_stats_textview"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/total_calories_drawable"/>
```

Comment: have you tested this? Doesn't work for me (applied on button though). Image is still cropped.

Comment: post in a new question with your xml

Comment: Perhaps you need to look if your theme is restricting this. This question was answered about 4 years ago, so a lot has changed. Additionally buttons may require different XML overrides to deal with different press states.

Comment: @ Shan Xeeshi what did you try?

Comment: Remember that you DO NOT use another XML drawable as source drawable in bitmap XML. To use this solution, you should use PNG or JPG drawables.

Answer (score 4):

Try as below...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/btndr" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, Keep your image as 9patch drawable.

You can add `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkmark"` to your textview. You can also set `drawablePadding` to keep the textview organized.

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
android:drawablePadding="2dip"
```

Here is the link to create 9patch [drawable](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

```
<TextView android:text="@string/txtUserName" 
android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
android:layout_width="160dip"
android:layout_height="60dip"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
android:drawablePadding="2dip"
/>
```

Comment: Try setting the plain drawable, If it is stretched or squeezed go for 9patch. @Tekno Freek.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, *setBounds* was not working for me so I had to do a workaround.

```
// Turn wanted drawable to bitmap
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somedrawable);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();

// I had a square image with same height and width so I needed only TextView height (getLineHeight)
int size = textView1.getLineHeight();
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, size, size, true));
textView1.setCompoundDrawables(d, null, null, null);

// Now we can set some spacing between text and image
textView1.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
```

It is not the best solution regarding performance because new bitmap is created, but still works.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a line with your desired height on drawable canvas and set as left drawable of your TextView. check this out:

```
public class FullHeightLineDrawable extends Drawable {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private int mHeight;

    public FullHeightLineDrawable(int height) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(CompatUtils.getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);

        mHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, -mHeight, 0, mHeight, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
final Drawable drawable = new FullHeightLineDrawable(getHeight());
mTextView.setTextColor(watchingColor);
mTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I abstract out this method. It works when the drawable is on the left of the TextView,dynamically scaling. If drawable is on the right side,this method doesn't work, needing to figure out why, but you can just directly use `textView.setcompounddrawableswithintrinsicbounds()` with the right-size Drawable resource

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public static void ajustCompoundDrawableSizeWithText(final TextView textView, final Drawable leftDrawable, final Drawable topDrawable, final Drawable rightDrawable, final Drawable bottomDrawable) {
    textView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
           if(leftDrawable != null){
               leftDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)textView.getTextSize(), (int)textView.getTextSize());
           }
            if(topDrawable != null){
                topDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)textView.getTextSize(), (int)textView.getTextSize());
            }
            if(rightDrawable != null){
                rightDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)textView.getTextSize(), (int)textView.getTextSize());
            }
            if(bottomDrawable != null){
                bottomDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)textView.getTextSize(), (int)textView.getTextSize());
            }
            textView.setCompoundDrawables(leftDrawable, topDrawable, rightDrawable, bottomDrawable);
                textView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Created a class that extends `TextView`, and resize the drawables in `onPreDrawListener`.

```
public class MyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style) {
        super(context, attrs, style);
        fitCompoundDrawableToLineHeight();
    }

    private void fitCompoundDrawableToLineHeight() {
        OnPreDraw.run(this, () -> {
            final Drawable[] cd = getCompoundDrawables();
            Arrays.stream(cd)
                .filter(drawable -> drawable != null)
                .forEach(d -> d.setBounds(0, 0, getLineHeight(), getLineHeight()));
            setCompoundDrawables(cd[0], cd[1], cd[2], cd[3]);
        });
    }
}

// Convenience class that abstracts onPreDraw logic
public class OnPreDraw {
    public static void run(View view, Runnable task) {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                if (!view.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
                    return true;
                }
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                task.run();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a one horizontal XML layout that has the blue line left and a textview right.
Than use that layout like an item and make a ListView of those items. Something like [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/), but a bit simpler