# not able to set android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_drawer" width of this

Tags: android

How to set the drawable left image size (width and height)?

```
android:id="@+id/cftvMainTitleWithIv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/login_title_height"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_drawer"
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
android:gravity="center"
android:text=""
```

Comment: I don't understand. what is the view used??

Comment: try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218486/android-fit-height-of-drawableleft-in-a-textview

Comment: Please provide the complete XML of this layout file of this view, so that we can be sure that what you have used is in fact a `TextView`; and how its parent view is interacting with it. Otherwise the property `drawableLeft` won't work on any other type of view.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set height and width for drawableLeft in xml. 
You can do `android:drawablePadding` or set proper height and width for textview and set the left drawable as background.

Comment: Refer this too http://w3facility.org/question/is-it-possible-to-scale-drawableleft-drawableright-in-textview/