# Resize drawable in TextView

Tags: android, textview, drawable

I am using the following code to attach the drawable to the TextView

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(text);
        tv.setTextSize(55);
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble);
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, android.R.drawable.presence_offline, 0);
```

The drawable is displayed but the only issue is that its really small comparing to the text, I'd like to rescale it and make it bigger but I haven't found a way of doing it.

Here's how the drawable looks like. Any suggestions?

[image: example]

Comment: this definitely doesn't work, have you put some thought into this answer?

Comment: I think this link can solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483828/is-it-possible-to-scale-drawableleft-drawableright-in-textview

Comment: can you please elaborate exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a 9-patch drawable.

A 9-patch drawable is a drawable that stretches based on it's content, and is very good for making backgrounds for views. 9-patch drawables are detected by ending with a .9.png extensions, and are just regular drawables where the first and last rows and columns of the image are used to determine which part should stretch and which part should stay the same way.

There is a tool for creating 9-patch drawables out of regular images called the Draw 9-patch tool, and it is located in the tools subdirectory of the android sdk directory, for windows it is `{SDK}\tools\draw9patch.bat`.

[9-patch documentation on the android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

[Draw 9-patch tool documentation on the android dev site](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)